# Child element wont work

Tags: css, css-selectors

i have a problem that if i type 1 nothing happen, but if i type 2 it make changes to the first div :S.

http://d.pr/m07l

do you know what im doing wrong

Comment: Can you paste some of your HTML and CSS code here? And what on earth do you mean by "type 1" and "type 2"? Type it where?

Comment: Do we know what you're doing wrong..? I don't think we even know what you're asking, or what you expect instead, or what's going wrong...could you clarify?

Comment: I suspect he's talking about the number in the `nth-child` and using `1`, which should affect the first child, is not. The first child is only affected when using `nth-child(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

`:nth-child()` is [1-indexed](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) and `:nth-child(1)` will select the first child. If it is not selecting what you want, there must be another child that is actually first. Maybe it's the *header*… in your example image.

Since it *is* the header (thanks for the link to [your site](http://sijdesign.dk/rap/)), you should use [`:nth-of-type()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) instead to consider just the `<div class="newsPost">` when counting.

Comment: Nailed it, see the comments under Quasdunk's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the first and the last child have their own selectors:

```
:first-child
```

and

```
:last-child
```

So you have to use `.newsPost:firstChild` instead of `.newsPost:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: `:first-child` is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)` and `:last-child` is equivalent to `:nth-last-child(1)`. All of them are valid selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, that's also what andyb said - I'm quite confused though, because it didn't work for me either. But it's been a while since I used this selector, so maybe some things have changed :) Should I delete my post?

Comment: i mean the nth-child(1) etc. i want to remove the margin-right: on the 3 and 6 class something like this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-work-backward-to-understand-css-structural-pseudo-classes/   but wont work for me :S

Comment: @Quasdunk: You may be testing in browsers that don't support `:nth-child()`, as `:first-child` appeared in CSS2 and has better browser (IE) support.